# Opencv Blur just within Circle

Tags: python, opencv

How does one blur a circular portion of an image in the python bindings of Open CV. Can one apply blurring on images without making new images?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like the OpenCV's blurring and filtering functions allow masking the input. I suggest applying the filter on a Rect around the circular portion, then assign the elements of the blurred sub matrix to the original image while masking the elements that do not correspond to the circle.